# Bluetooth Sending data.. App crashing

Tags: android, android-activity, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

Ok, so I have 2 classes, one pairs with devices and the other sends data.

My pairing class works fine nothing there is a problem.

But my sending data class crashes soon as I open it because of this openBT() funtion, I removed that and the try catch statement and my activity works again so I know it's that.

Here is the code I have:

```
        try {
        openBT();
    } catch (IOException e)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bluetooth not connected, are you sure you paired with the NPU?", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    void openBT() throws IOException {

    UUID uuid = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");
    mmSocket = mmDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);
    mmSocket.connect();
    mmOutputStream = mmSocket.getOutputStream();
    mmInputStream = mmSocket.getInputStream();
}
```

Now... I am not connected to any bluetooth device but because of the try catch statement I thought the activity will still load and then just throw my toast, meaning something else is wrong, is this correct or is it still going to crash? I can't test on any bluetooth devices for a while.

Also another thing, I found this openBT() code online in a tutorial.. because I am paired with a device, is this code enough to open a connection with that certain device.. using that UUID(which must be for any paired?)

Logcat:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                               java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{funnysystems.fun/funnysystems.fun.NPUBTControl}: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2224)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2274)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:150)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1276)
                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5153)
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
                                                   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                   at funnysystems.fun.NPUBTControl.openBT(NPUBTControl.java:82)
                                                   at funnysystems.fun.NPUBTControl.onCreate(NPUBTControl.java:56)
                                                   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2188)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2274) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:150) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1276) 
                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5153) 
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793) 
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560) 
                                                   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

01-17 11:50:34.645 908-1429/? W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity funnysystems.fun/.NPUBTControl

Comment: Please post your logcat

Comment: Can you check if mmDevice is null?

Comment: sorry I get what u mean.. will check now.

Comment: @fractalwrench, yes it seems null? what does that mean?

Comment: It means you're trying to open a socket to a device which doesn't exist (as far as your app is concerned). You need to make sure the device is initialised before attempting to open a socket

Comment: @fractalwrench ah thanks, I thought it could be that but I thought the exception would be catched... and output my toast... weird..

Comment: You are only catching `IOException` and not the `NullPointerException` that is thrown so your toast is not shown.